How to insert image to google forms using apps script?
I have a google forms with image upload. I captured onSubmit event value and process it to make a new google sheets. I have difficulties in inserting the image that is stored on google drive to the newly created sheet. My current script to insert the image looks like this:
    function insertImage(sheet) {

  const urlRaw = sheet.getRange('C42').getValue();
  if (!urlRaw) {
    console.log('No URL provided in cell C42.');
    return;
  }

  // Extract the file ID from the URL
  let fileId;
  if (urlRaw.includes("open?id=")) {
    fileId = urlRaw.split("open?id=")[1].split("&")[0];
  } else if (urlRaw.includes("/d/")) {
    fileId = urlRaw.split("/d/")[1].split("/")[0];
  } else {
    console.error("Invalid Google Drive URL format.");
    return;
  }

  const imgRange = sheet.getRange('C42')
  const imgUrl = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).getUrl()
  sheet.insertImage(imgUrl,imgRange.getColumn(), imgRange.getRow())

}


Use .getBlob() to Insert Images from Google Drive into Google Sheets
Instead of using .getUrl, I used .getBlob to get the image as a Blob, which directly handled the image data. I also removed the imgUrl and passed the Blob directly to insertImage.
I changed this part of your code:
const imgRange = sheet.getRange('C42')
      sheet.insertImage(DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).getBlob(), imgRange.getColumn(), imgRange.getRow())

Complete Code:
function insertImage() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const urlRaw = sheet.getRange('C42').getValue();
  if (!urlRaw) {
    console.log('No URL provided in cell C42.');
    return;
  }

  let fileId;
  if (urlRaw.includes("open?id=")) {
    fileId = urlRaw.split("open?id=")[1].split("&")[0];
  } else if (urlRaw.includes("/d/")) {
    fileId = urlRaw.split("/d/")[1].split("/")[0];
  } else {
    console.error("Invalid Google Drive URL format.");
    return;
  }
  const imgRange = sheet.getRange('C42')
  sheet.insertImage(DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).getBlob(), imgRange.getColumn(), imgRange.getRow())
}

Note: The file size of the image may also cause an error.
Sample Output:

Reference:
getBlob()

I made a small modification to the func you provide for it to work. Thanks!

If this answers your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon) and upvote the answer.  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.  If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. how to accept the answer
